# Keycloak: get all users without password

Tags: keycloak

I am customizing Keycloak. Now I want to get a list with all users, that have not set a password yet. In the web interface I can check if a user has a password, like this (no password set):

[image]

What I want is something like this:

```
session.users()
        .getUsersStream(session.getContext().getRealm())
        .filter(userModel -> user.isPasswordSet() == false)
        ...
```

Is there a functionality like isPasswordSet(), so that I can retrieve a list of all users without a password?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but programmatically I think you can do something similar to:

Use the [UserCredentialStoreManager](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/credential/UserCredentialStoreManager.html#UserCredentialStoreManager-org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession-) class

```
UserCredentialStoreManager user_credentials_store_manager =  UserCredentialStoreManager(session)
```

and use the method [isConfiguredFor](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/UserCredentialManager.html#isConfiguredFor-org.keycloak.models.RealmModel-org.keycloak.models.UserModel-java.lang.String-)

> boolean isConfiguredFor(RealmModel realm,
> UserModel user,
> String type)
>
> Checks to see if user has credential type configured. Looks in UserStorageProvider or
> UserFederationProvider first, then loops through each
> CredentialProvider.

In your case you want to check for the type [PasswordCredentialModel.TYPE](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/credential/PasswordCredentialModel.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found the PasswordCredentialProvider class where I can call "getPassword" with the user model!

Answer (score 1):

This API can check user has a password or not
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/test/users/{user-id}/credentials

I demo two user, one user(set-password-user) already set the password.
other user(no-password-user) not yet set the password.

1. "set-password-user" assign the role as "manage-users"
   [image]
2. get an access-token
   [image]
3. get the user list
   [image]
4. get the credential of "set-password-user"
   [image]
5. get the credential of "no-password-user"
   [image]

You can see difference between 4. and 5.
So you can make user.isPasswordSet() function with #4/5's results

Comment: Thanks, this is working. For a programatically solution it worked with PasswordCredentialProvider.